# Why do UDP connections only require a socket on one endpoint?

Tags: udp

I thought for a long time that sockets were defined as an end point of a two way connection, however UDP sockets can be created without the other end making a socket to keep the connection live.

**What is the exact reason for this?**

I always thought it was because during a TCP connection, the other end user needs to communicate back by sending acknowledgements, while UDP they don't. I;ve just guessed that and never *exactly* known why.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hello JD and welcome to Network Engineering!

Unlike TCP, UDP protocol does not require connection to be established, therefore sending host not waiting for confirmation of transmission or anything. Receiving side can check that data transfered are correct by checksum validation.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought for a long time that sockets were defined as an end point of a two way connection, however UDP sockets ...

Unlike TCP, UDP does not know the concept of a "connection" at all. UDP is used to send packets that don't belong to a connection to the port of another computer. UDP can even be used to send "multicast" packets that are sent to multiple computers.

You may also send an UDP packet to some computer and receive the "answer" from a completely different computer (as you see it in the Teredo protocol).

Andrey Prokhorov writes in his answer that UDP does "not require" a connection to be established;

however because UDP does not know the concept of connections, it is even *impossible* that a connection is established.